# Can a byte-range in a m3u8 playlist be length 0?

Tags: playlist, zero, m3u8, http-live-streaming

According to the [HLS Pantos spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-13#section-3.4.1), a byte-range in a m3u8 playlist should look like `#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:<n>[@<o>]` where "n is a decimal-integer indicating the length of the sub-range in bytes".

However, this doesn't specify if "n" can be 0 or negative.  This is a particular issue for caption playlists which may have a gap where no captions appear...

Is this a valid playlist?

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXTINF:10.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:100@0
media.ts
#EXTINF:10.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:0@100
media.ts
#EXTINF:10.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:50@100
media.ts
```

Comment: What did you end up doing to solve this? I have a similar situation, where a caption playlist may have empty segments (i.e. no captions during that time range).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, playlist entries with a byte-range length of 0 are NOT valid.

Answer (score 0):

Byte-range can not be zero in any case. I don't think any streamer will send zero value for this.